# redis+elk stack using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elastic-stack

I am trying to set up redis+ELK stack with docker. I wish to use redis to accept the logs from a remote location and forward them to logstash.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:latest
  command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
  volumes:
    - /root/ebs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

logstash:
  build: logstash/
  command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
  volumes:
    - ./logstash/config:/etc/logstash/conf.d
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
kibana:
  build: kibana/
  volumes:
    - ./kibana/config/:/opt/kibana/config/
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
  links:
    - elasticsearch

redis:
  image: redis:latest
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  links:
    -  logstash
```

And here is my logstash.conf

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5000
    }
    redis {
        host => "redis:6379"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    }
}
```

My logstash container is throwing this error:

```
logstash_1       | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-06T09:21:35.258000+0000", :message=>"An unexpected error occurred!", :error=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass>, :class=>"NoMethodError",
```

Comment: Does the setup work outside of Docker? Is it really a container issue or an issue in the application? Also, what have you tried already? When does the error occur? What were you trying to do? Very hard to debug with just the info you provided

Comment: I haven't tried the setup outside of Docker. It is pretty simple really, I am missing something stupid. How can you use redis with logstash?

Answer (score 0):

I can see one immediate issue. In your logstash.conf file you specify the redis hostname:

```
redis {
    host => "redis:6379"
}
```

In your docker-compose file however you do not actually link the redis service into your logstash service:

```
logstash:
  <snip>
  links:
    - elasticsearch
```

Instead you link your logstash service into your redis service. As far as I can understand you want your redis container's port to be available to logstash, not the other way around. You should remove the `logstash` link in your redis service and add a `redis` link in your logstash service. So:

```
logstash:
  <snip>
  links:
    - elasticsearch
    - redis
```

I can't positively say that this is the cause of the error message though.

Edit: The configuration for the redis input might also be wrong. According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-redis.html#plugins-inputs-redis) the port should be specified as a separate property like this:

```
redis {
    host => "redis"
    port => 6379
}
```

Comment: Another possible error is the `host => "redis:6379"`. I think the port should be specified by a separate `port` property. So something akin to:

host => "redis"
port => 6379

Worth a try.